# "Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off." after trying to wget from a server

Tags: timestamp, wget, unix-timestamp

Following [this](http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html) manual, I'm trying to `wget` only the files that have been changed after the last `wget`.

After executing `wget -S *link to server*` the file is downloaded, but the timestamp of the file is the one from the local system, rather than that of the machine(by using `ls -l` as you can imagine)

And, when I execute `wget -N *link to server*`, the file gets downloaded(regardless of it not having any chances made to it) and at the end of the output of the command is the following line:
`Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.`

My question is: Why does the timestamping not work? How do I resolve that warning?

Comment: Did you check whether the server is actually sending a `Last-modified` header? (Try `curl --head <url>`). If not, there is nothing that wget can do to fix this.

Comment: There actually isn't one... Are you aware of a way to include it?

Comment: Depends on the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified recommends to use `If-Modified-Since` request headers instead. That might solve your problem.

Comment: But are you aware of any way to "force" the server into including that header? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not as a client. Depends on the server config. For example, serving a static HTML page may include the header, and a PHP-generated page might not. That's what `If-Modified-Since` was invented for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the timestamping not work?

*Server* fails to deliver [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) response headers, which is required for [Time-Stamping](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html)

> Note that time-stamping will only work for files for which the server
> gives a timestamp. For HTTP, this depends on getting a `Last-Modified`
> header.(...)

> How do I resolve that warning?

As explained in order to make it work you would need to alter *server* in giving said response headers, otherwise to avoid outputing warning, just do not use `-N` option.

Comment: But is there a way to do that? Make the server send the required header? Some `.conf` I need to modify or something?